# Steps in solving the equivalence of the set statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$ \overline{(B \setminus A) \cup (B\bigoplus A)} \equiv \overline{A\bigoplus B} $$

Hi guys how to solve or to prove the equivalence of this statement?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Welcome  to Mathematics SE! I've edited your question to remove the link to an image. Please avoid posting images in the future for the sake of your readers :-)

Comment: Thank you sir and officials i'm just newbie here hope u can help me to prove this equivalence of this set :))))

Comment: What is $\oplus$ in this context?

Comment: ⊕ means exclusive OR

Answer (score 0):

This equivalence can be shown using properties of the operators involved, as well as De Morgan's laws. The main properties we'll need are commutativity, associativity, and idempotence of set intersection, as well as the fact that the symmetric difference of two sets is equal to the union of pairwise set differences.

Here is a purely symbolic manipulation showing the two are equal:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\overline{(B \setminus A) \cup (B \oplus A)}
&=& \overline{(B \setminus A)} \cap \overline{(B \oplus A)} \\
&=& \overline{(B \setminus A)} \cap \overline{(B \setminus A) \cup (A \setminus B)} \\
&=& \overline{(B \setminus A)} \cap \overline{(B \setminus A)} \cap \overline{(A \setminus B)} \\
&=& \overline{(B \setminus A)} \cap \overline{(A \setminus B)} \\
&=& \overline{(A \setminus B)} \cap \overline{(B \setminus A)} \\
&=& \overline{(A \setminus B)\cup(B \setminus A)} \\
&=& \overline{(A \oplus B)}
\end{eqnarray}$$

The first, third, and sixth equalities follow from De Morgan's laws. The second and seventh equalities follow from the property of symmetric difference stated above. The fourth and fifth equalities follow from the idempotence and commutativity of set intersection, respectively.